# How to decode a URL in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, encoding, decode

I am trying to decode a URL and also format it with `URL` module in `nodejs`.

```js
const url = require('url');

const oldUrl = "https://tut.by/ad=%24%7Baccount.domain%7D";
const newUrl = url.parse(oldUrl, true).format();
```

Here is the returned value for `newUrl`

```
{ 
   auth: null
   hash: null
   host: "tut.by"
   hostname: "tut.by"
   href: "https://tut.by/?ad=%24%7Baccount.domain%7D"
   path: "/?ad=%24%7Baccount.domain%7D"
   pathname: "/"
   port: null
   protocol: "https:"
   query: {ad: "${account.domain}"}
   search: "?ad=%24%7Baccount.domain%7D"
   slashes: true 
}
```

When I finally format it like this:

```js
const formattedUrl = newUrl.format();
```

It returned:

```
https://tut.by/?ad=%24%7Baccount.domain%7D
```

But the expected result is:

```
https://tut.by/?ad=${account.domain}
```

How to handle this situation so it returns the correctly decoded URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
decodeURIComponent(newUrl);
```

```js
console.log(decodeURIComponent('https://tut.by/?ad=%24%7Baccount.domain%7D'))
```